# Nested if statement is confusing Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to set up a dropdown menu that pulls from a Datatable. This works just fine for the first level of the menu.

**Working code:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in menu.Rows)
{
    if (Level1 != dr["Level1"].ToString())
    {
        <li><a href="#">@dr["Level1"].ToString()</a></li>
        Level1 = @dr["Level1"].ToString();
    }
}
</ul>
```

The problem occurs when I try to add a nested if statement. If you put this code into Visual Studio you will notice that the closing bracket for the `@foreach` loop is not recognized by Razor.

**Code breaks:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in menu.Rows)
{
    if (Level1 != dr["Level1"].ToString())
    {
        <li><a href="#">@dr["Level1"].ToString()</a></li>
        Level1 = @dr["Level1"].ToString();

        if (Level2 != dr["Level2"].ToString())
        {
            <li><a href="#">@dr["Level2"].ToString()</a></li>
            Level2 = @dr["Level2"].ToString();                                        
        } 
    }
} <!-- the issue is the bracket on this line -->
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you have found a Razor bug! Congratulations :)

Comment: No bug, just an invalid @-sign in the code region.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the offending section in `<text>` tags. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6099659/1451531

Comment: +1 for the relevant link, although the <text> hack didn't work

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need to write the `@` in front of `@dr[...]` in the lines where you assign the value to `LevelX`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in menu.Rows)
{
    if (Level1 != dr["Level1"].ToString())
    {
        <li><a href="#">@dr["Level1"].ToString()</a></li>
        Level1 = dr["Level1"].ToString(); // no need here

        if (Level2 != dr["Level2"].ToString())
        {
            <li><a href="#">@dr["Level2"].ToString()</a></li>
            Level2 = dr["Level2"].ToString();     // and no need here                                   
        } 
    }
} <!-- the issue is the bracket on this line -->
</ul>
```

---

### EDIT

To address the question, why the closing bracket is not recognized.

**TL;DR**
As you are **again in code-region you do not need the `@`-sign**.

**Details**
The `<li>...</li>` section defines a ***html*-region**, where text is **interpreted as *html***.
Directly after the closing `</li>` the **outer *code*-region is active again** and text is **interpreted as *C#*-code**. Therefore an assignment to `Level1` is possible. Adding an `@`-sign to `dr` *here* has the same consequences as in an "normal" cs-file:
It's a syntax-error.

Comment: He doesn't need them indeed, but this doesn't address the question. Thanks for the note though.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4946841/2518285), if a line is being interpreted as markup instead of code, put @ in front of it. If a line is being interpreted as code instead of markup, put @: in front of it.