# MVC Closing Tags error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Could anybody spot what's causing this to produce " The using block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup." ?

```
    <div class="tabContentHolder">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProcurement", "FMR", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formSaveProcurement", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="btnContainer">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Coordinator") || User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                <a href="#" id="lnkProcurementSave">Save Changes</a>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FMRID);
            }
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    <div class="tabContentTitle">Notice of Award and Notice to Proceed</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.IssueDateNAward)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.IssueDateNAward)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.NAAmount)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NAAmount)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.NAContractId)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NAContractId)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.IssueDateNProceed)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.IssueDateNProceed)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.NPIssuedBy)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NPIssuedBy)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.NPDesgination)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NPDesgination)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabContentTitle">Contract</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ContractorName)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContractorName)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ContractorRepresentative)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContractorRepresentative)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ContractorAddress)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContractorAddress)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabContentTitle">Admin</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LGUName)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LGUName)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LGURepresentative)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LGURepresentative)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LGUAddress)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LGUAddress)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabContentTitle">Dimensions</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.FMRLength)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FMRLength)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.RoadbedWidth)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RoadbedWidth)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PavementWidth)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PavementWidth)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PavementThickness)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PavementThickness)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabContentTitle">Coordinates</div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.StartLatitude)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartLatitude)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.EndLatitude)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndLatitude)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.StartLongitude)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartLongitude)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.EndLongitude)</div>
        <div class="itemValue">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndLongitude)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabContentTitle">Scope of Work</div>
    @foreach(var item in Model.ScopeOfWork){
    <div class="itemHolder">
        <div class="itemTitle"><label>@item.ScopeText</label></div>
        <div class="itemValue">Quantity: &nbsp; <label>@item.Quantity</label> &nbsp;&nbsp; Cost: &nbsp; <label>@item.Cost</label></div>
    </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

Comment: I see no problem here. Could you please clean/rebuild the solution or restart your visual studio?

Comment: Change `@foreach` to `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

The only error I can see *(resharper can see on my local recreation of your Razor syntax)* is with your `@foreach`

Once you're inside a code block (which in this case you are, because of your `@using` you don't need to use `@` any more)

Try changing your `@foreach` to

```
    foreach (var item in Model.ScopeOfWork)
    {
        <div class="itemHolder">
            <div class="itemTitle"><label>@item.ScopeText</label></div>
            <div class="itemValue">Quantity: &nbsp; <label>@item.Quantity</label> &nbsp;&nbsp; Cost: &nbsp; <label>@item.Cost</label></div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why @foreach doesn't work there? Thanks!

Comment: I already did - `Once you're inside a code block (which in this case you are, because of your @using you don't need to use @ any more)`

Comment: See here for some more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099504/question-about-nested-code-block-declarations-in-razor

Comment: Thanks @Alex. This answer helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099659/5071902

Comment: @RenanAraújo no problem :)

Comment: I tried cleaning, building and rebuilding the solution. Also changing @foreach to foreach. Still its producing the same error as above.

Comment: @AllenNickoBalatan there must be something else hiding in your markup... is this the full file? Are you getting this error on run or on build?

Comment: On run, there's no problem on building/rebuilding. I'm looking right now on the other files connected to this. I'll inform you if ever I've found this nuisance.

Comment: if you're loading in partials on the same page, it could well be in one of those