# asp.net mvc what is the good way to post data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with strong typed model.
I have a popup (done with jquery slide) which some data from model.
it has a button SEND which must send data to controller.
Some of those requires validation (email for example).
I also has some properties of model inside the view.
They all together must be send to a controller.

How this can be done ? If possible some examples

Thank you

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454232/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-full-model-from-view-to-controller

Comment: this is not duplicate. i dont need (i guess) beginform because this will work for whole webpage, but i need to send email from popup

Comment: Please add the code for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To send a partial data from your form, collect those information and send it as a JSON using jQuery ajax.

The MVC's built in [`JsonValueProviderFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonvalueproviderfactory%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helps to bind JSON

```
$.post('/controller/action',{data:JSON.stringify(myData)},function(){


});
```

Comment: ok, some questions: 1) this should be done in js func so i need to pass each model's property as parameter ? 2) what about validation. i need to check one for email, second is required. 3) there wont be any server-side validation ?

Comment: @Alexander, The validation can be fired manually by calling a validate() method from jquery validate plugin