# Why does Razor still need prefix '@' before Html.DropDownListFor within c# source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Recently I am coding in a cshtml file in a ASP.NET MVC project. Following code is odd and I cannot understand Why does Razor still need prefix '@' before @Html.DropDownListFor?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
……
   for (var i = 0; i < Model.TotalLevel; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[i], Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "string", new {@class = "hidden department"})
                    ;
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[i], Model.Departments, "string", new {@class = "department"})
                    ;
            }
        }
}
```

According to [Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946334/unexpected-foreach-keyword-after-character) ,  `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[i], Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "string", new {@class = "hidden department"})` is indeed inside c# source, so there is no need to add `@`before the statement. However, if not, the view didn't display drowdown list. So in fact `@` is needed before Html though it's in c# source.

Anyone can tell me why? Is the accepted answer from [Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946334/unexpected-foreach-keyword-after-character) miss something?

Comment: `Html.DropDownListFor()` would just execute the method (it would not return anything). The leading `@` means that the result of method is rendered in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please offer some official url verifying that?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) and [this](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/258/usage-of-the-at-sign-in-asp-net) might help. Without the leading `@` , you would need to assign the return value of `Html.DropDownListFor()` (a `MvcHtmlString`) to a variable and then output the result to the view - `@{ var ddl = Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID); @ddl }`